# How to auto increment serial number of result on page like 1,2,3

Tags: php, html

I want to auto increment serial number of result fetched from query on page like 1,2,3......

Below is my piece of code:

```
<td><font size="-1"><?php echo $++i ?> </font></td><td><font size="-1">
```

Now `<?php echo $++i ?>` fetches actual row id which is 17,18 of a table.
      i want just simple value 1,2,3...so on

Comment: Just store it in a counter variable and increment it each time through the loop.

Comment: You need to explain what you want WAY better next question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your table row you can echo incremented variable (simple counter):

```
<?php $i = 0; ?>
...
<tr><td><?php echo ++$i;?></td><td><font size="-1"><?php echo $row['id']; ?> </font></td></tr>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could start your own variable and increment it, but it might be easier for you to instead subtract to get the value you want. change you code from:

```
<?php echo $row['id']-16; ?>
```

to

```
<?php echo $row['id']-16; ?>
```

an example you can run to show this works:

```
<?php $row  = array('id' => '17'); ?>
<?php for($row['id']; $row['id']<40; $row['id']++){ ?>
<?php echo $row['id']-16; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: No idea why this working code that solves the problem would get a -1, sometimes SO befuddles me. At least a comment to tell why would be nice.

Comment: That's not a reason to mark someone's answer down. Ask for an explanation.

Comment: I think it's because the user wants pagination - so page 2 will have results 16-31, 3 32-47, and so on. I believe he's after a way to generate the page numbers, and the code here won't do that. (Though the question isn't entirely clear)

Comment: My point is that his variable is already auto-incremented and he just needs to adjust it.

Comment: @DrCord, I explain why you probably minused. We have fetched id from the query. So it must be the primary key of some database table. Id's usually have skips: for example 17,18,19,25,27,29. That is happen because of deleted rows. So we need here simple counter.

Comment: My answer or VG's explanation of why my answer sucks?